# TypeORM cascades strange behaviour

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, typeorm, cascade

I have ManyToOne/OneToMany relationship. Group can have multiple reservations, reservation belong to one group. Both have soft-delete implemented. What happens is when I soft delete group typeorm executes UPDATE query to set groupId to null in reservations table. I tried to remove `cascade: ['soft-remove']` option and leave it without any cascade options- same problem persist. I even tried to add `onDelete: 'NO ACTION'` still nothing. Any ideas why it uses `onDelete: 'SET NULL'`without me doing anything to it? Any ideas how to fix it? I had these relations before and `cascade: ['soft-remove']` on parent entity always worked wonders, I even opened my other projects and checked if I'm using it in the same way, and well... I do. Can not figure out why now it behaves weird af.

Comment: What do you expect for the `groupId` of reservations where the group is deleted?

Comment: Since it is soft delete I expect for it to remain the same

Comment: And how do you delete the `group` (parent)? Can you share some code of how you handle this? Also share both models `Group` and `Reservation`.

Answer (score 0):

Add below key-value to options argument in @ManyToOne side of the relation i.e. Reservation

```
orphanedRowAction: 'soft-delete'
```

I keep `cascade: true` in @OneToMany side of the relation Group, you can try that or `cascade: ['soft-remove']`